# Loop over array of values with "ignore rule" fallback in Drools spreadsheet

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule

I have a quite simple problem: for a rule I want to specifie an array of values which are valid values. How can I do so? I already had a look on the "in" keyword, but if I use the keyword I get a very strange exception from the Drools Compiler.

[image: Working example with "in"]

This image shows the working rule with the "in" keyword. But I also want the user to be able to mark the rule as "ignorable" if needed, for example using a special character..

If I use the following rule with the "ignore rule"-Extra (which I also use in other rules with success), I get a very strange error message from the Drools Compiler:

[image: Not working rule]

Error message from the compiler:

```
Unable to Analyse Expression plant == "91" || plant == "83" || plant == "63" || plant == "28" || "91":
[Error: Right side of logical operation is not of type boolean. Found class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... lant == "83" || plant == "63" || plant == "28" || "91" ....}]
                                                           ^
[Line: 9, Column: 2] : [Rule name='CAS_11']

Predicate '"83"' must be a Boolean expression
[Line: 9, Column: 2] : [Rule name='CAS_11']

Predicate '"63"' must be a Boolean expression
[Line: 9, Column: 2] : [Rule name='CAS_11']
```

I hope you guys can help me.. I am very new to Drools which might be the problem ;)...

C YA

Comment: Could be related to this [possible regression bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263258/drools-date-coercion-and-conditional-or) in OR conditions

Comment: By the way, I believe that in your second case $param will be the complete list of values, so the comparison comes out as `"91", "83", "63", "28" == "-"`

Comment: Hmm.. that could be the problem.. Do you have any solution how to build a "ignore this rule" fallback??? I want the user either to choose between setting a specific value or mark this condition of the rule as to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to change you your condition like

```
plant in ($param) && "-" not in ($param)
```

With this `"91","28","63"` fires the rule, but `"93","28","-"` does not. Plain `"-"` ignores the rule as well.

If you want a fancier solution you could and another fact to your domain, such as Ignore with one boolean attribute, and have another condition for that. Details of this solutions requires a bit more info on your actual use case, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! That was what I was searching for ;)!